# Cisco 2921 PBR License Question

Tags: cisco, router, pbr

Does anyone know what license is required on a Cisco 2921 router to use Policy Based routing?

**Here is my show version output:**

```
 Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2013 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 26-Feb-13 03:42 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M16, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

xyzwer uptime is 8 weeks, 6 days, 23 hours, 23 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at 16:58:59 EST Wed Dec 20 2017
System image file is "flash0:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.152-4.M3.bin"
Last reload type: Normal Reload
Last reload reason: Reload Command



This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco CISCO2921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 909312K/40960K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FGL171511XH
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
2 Serial interfaces
1 terminal line
2 Channelized T1/PRI ports
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity enabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
250880K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)


License Info:

License UDI:

-------------------------------------------------
Device#   PID                   SN
-------------------------------------------------
*0        CISCO2921/K9          FGL171511XH     



Technology Package License Information for Module:'c2900' 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Technology    Technology-package           Technology-package
              Current       Type           Next reboot  
------------------------------------------------------------------
ipbase        ipbasek9      Permanent      ipbasek9
security      securityk9    Permanent      securityk9
uc            None          None           None
data          None          None           None

Configuration register is 0x2102
```

Comment: Only IPbase is required for policy based routing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Cisco Feature Navigator](http://cfn.cloudapps.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp) performing a research by software, the IPBase has the Policy Based Routing (PBR) feature:

[image]

Comment: thanks, i just wanted to make sure my problem i'm having was not a simple licensing issue.